# parallel ajax calls - fail to receive response from the first

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm implementing a little "ping" utility to check if our two servers are online.

here is the javascript code:

```
var t1, t2, t3, t4;

function jsContactServers() {
    ajaxServerStatusWWW();
    ajaxServerStatusAPPS();
}

function ajaxServerStatusWWW() {
    try {                   
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        var t1 = setTimeout(function() {
            xmlhttp.abort();
            clearTimeout(t1);
            ServerIsDown("www");
        }, 7000);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {           
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var strOut;
                strOut = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log("www:" + strOut);
                if (strOut == "1") {
                    clearTimeout(t1);
                    document.getElementById("divwww").innerHTML = "www : UP";
                    document.getElementById("divwww").style.background = "green";
                    pauseSound("alarm_internet");
                    pauseSound("alarm_server");
                    setTimeout(ajaxServerStatusWWW, 10000);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("www");
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.mydomain.com/contactserver.php?IP=1.2.3.4",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}

function ajaxServerStatusAPPS() {
    try {                   
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        var t2 = setTimeout(function() {
            xmlhttp.abort();
            clearTimeout(t2);
            ServerIsDown("apps");
        }, 7000);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {           
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var strOut;
                strOut = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log("apps:" + strOut);
                if (strOut == "1") {
                    clearTimeout(t2);
                    document.getElementById("divapps").innerHTML = "apps : UP";
                    document.getElementById("divapps").style.background = "green";
                    setTimeout(ajaxServerStatusAPPS, 10000);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("apps");
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.mydomain.com/contactserver.php?IP=4.3.2.1",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

the contactserver.php tries to read a .php file in the server declared in the IP GET parameter and returns "1" if the php file can be read (server is up).

Now, the problem is, I do get a reply from

```
ajaxServerStatusAPPS();
```

but i get **no reply at all** from

```
ajaxServerStatusWWW();
```

[`console.log("www:" + strOut);` doesn't fire ]

However if I initially only call ajaxServerStatusWWW() instead of both, it works properly. It also works properly if i make the call **synchronous** instead of **asynchronous** by changing the

```
xmlhttp.open("...", true) ;
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("...", false);
```

Am I missing something in the process? why is this happening ?

Comment: what does your console say? can you actually see both of the requests in your network tab? any errors in the response, 500 headers etc?

Comment: As an aside (sorry, no time right now to read your code in detail), your code is begging to be made more modular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): You don't declare `xmlhttp`, so it's an implicit global, and so the call to `ajaxServerStatusAPPS` overwrites the value that the call to `ajaxServerStatusWWW` stored in that variable. Both functions try to use the same variable.

Within `ajaxServerStatusWWW` and `ajaxServerStatusAPPS`, declare the variable using `var` so they each have their own.

On modern browsers, you can make doing this an *error* rather than an implicit global by using "strict" mode. When you assign to an unknown identifier in strict mode, it causes a `ReferenceError` rather than creating a global.

Comment: life saver. my mistake, didn't notice that.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror also, not related to your problem, but you might want to look into combining the 2 functions by making the type of server (www or apps) and the address parameters for your combined function. If you ever need to update your app for some reason (like dropping support for activeXobject), you'll only have to do it in one place.