# Few simultaneously ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make few (3 in the following example) ajax calls simultaneously.
In doOnload (fired by onload event) i call function load with different arguments.

Here is the code:

```
function doOnload()
{
    load(0, 10);
    load(10, 10);
    load(20, 10);
}

function load(offset, length)
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.offset = offset;

    var nocache = '&token=' + Math.random();

    url = 'load.php?offset=' + offset + '&length=' + length + nocache;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = process_request_status_change;
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function process_response()
{
    var div;
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var main = document.getElementById('main');

    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
    {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = json[i];
        main.appendChild(div);

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));
    }
}

function process_request_status_change()
{
    if (xhr.readyState === 4)
    {
        if (xhr.status === 200)
        {
            process_response();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('%c Server side issue', 'color: red;');
        }
    }
}
```

the code of load.php:

```
$list = range(0, 1000);

$offset = isset($_GET['offset'])    ? $_GET['offset']   : 0;
$length = isset($_GET['length'])    ? $_GET['length']   : sizeof($list);

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array_slice($list, $offset, $length));
```

Expected behavior:
adding (in random order) to main element 3 sequences in 10 div tags

Actual behavior:
in html code added last sequence only, but it can be added 1, 3 or 7 times.

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parallel ajax calls - fail to receive response from the first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765590/parallel-ajax-calls-fail-to-receive-response-from-the-first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). This line:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

creates/sets a **global** variable, not a local one. So what's happening is that each time you call the function, you're overwriting the previous value of `xhr`.

To make it local to the function, put `var` in front of it. You'll also have to move the functions that require access to that variable *into* the `load` function, so they close over it. (Don't worry, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

---

Astonishingly, this [isn't even the first time **today**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19765668/157247) I've answered this. :-)